# Python requests returns 200 but scrapy returns 301/302

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

I want to make some post requests to this url: `http://31.193.137.143/whill/locator2/public/results`.

I was using python requests and it worked well. The status code I got from the response of this post request is 200, which is the same as what I get from the website (`http://31.193.137.143/whill/locator2/public`). However later I want to incorporate it into my code base which is using scrapy. I found that the response I get now has a status code of either 301 or 302. And the content is basically nothing. I also noticed that the body of the request is now empty instead of the key value pairs I passed at the beginning.

What could be the problem?

Code using python request

```
def get_location(lat, lng, p = {'http': os.environ['http_proxy'], 'https': os.environ['https_proxy']}):
    ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
    try:
        r = requests.post('http://31.193.137.143/whill/locator2/public/results', data = {'lat': lat, 'lng': lng},
                      verify = False, proxies = p, headers = {'User-Agent': ua})
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['address', 'name', 'id'])
        tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
        shops = tree.xpath('//div[@class="inner-marker-data"]')
        df['address'] = [''.join(s.xpath('./span[@class="marker-address"]/text()')) for s in shops]
        df['name'] = [''.join(s.xpath('./h3/text()')) for s in shops]
        df['id'] = [s.xpath('./a/@data-item-id')[0] for s in shops]
        return df
    except:
        print(lat, lng)
        return pd.DataFrame()
```

Code using scrapy:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
import pandas as pd
import json
from shapely import geometry
import time

class WHSpider(Spider):
    name = 'WilliamHill'
    url = 'http://31.193.137.143/whill/locator2/public/results'
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUEST_PER_IP': 5
    }
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302]
    headers = {
        'Proxy-Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Origin': 'http://31.193.137.143',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Referer': 'http://31.193.137.143/whill/locator2/public/',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    }

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = pd.DataFrame()

    def start_requests(self):
        geo = json.load(open('*.json'))
        geo = [(g['town'], float(g['latitude']), float(g['longitude']), g['postcode']) for g in geo]
        for i in range(len(geo)):
            name, lat, lng, code = geo[i]
            for latitude, longitude in set(list(geometry.Point(lat, lng).buffer(.1, resolution = 1).exterior.coords)):
                request_body = json.dumps({'lat': latitude, 'lng': longitude, '_token': 'eKz2cHSu5EX7zKZGy3w226nCQpBUYHti1QFf99bO'})
                yield Request(self.url, method = 'POST', body = request_body, callback = self.parse, headers = self.headers, dont_filter = True)


    def parse(self, response):
        <do something>
```

Comment: First guess: `requests` follows the redirection, `scrapy` doesn't.

Comment: @chepner. Thanks for your comments. It is interesting that I just looked at the redirect log in  chrome dev tools as well as `response.history` from python request but neither of these two show any redirection.

Comment: I even disallow redirect in python requests and got the results I expected. So there is no redirecting happening. Then what is wrong with scrapy?

Comment: When you put 301 and 302 on handle_httpstatus_list the RedirectMIddleware will not redirect the request, instead it will return the 302 request for you. Remove this line and the code should work.